# How do you install ubuntu on a pre-installed windows7 system

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

How do you install ubuntu on a pre-installed windows7 system which usually comes with the max of 4 primary partitions already used up by the windows 7 installation. As these systems do not come with a windows system disk you cannot simply re-install windows if you mess up. So getting it right first time is critically important. I have seen some great instructions on www.avoiderrors.net but none deal with this specific but very common situation encountered by new users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), it is an officially supported installer for Windows users that allows Ubuntu to be installed and uninstalled in a safe, easy way as with any other Windows application.

Once you are done download Run Wubi, insert a password for the new account, adjust other settings such as the disk space, and click "install".

The installation process from this point on is fully automatic.

The installation files (approximately 700MB) will be downloaded and checked, after which you will be asked to reboot.

Do so and select Ubuntu at the boot screen. The installation will continue for another 10 to 15 minutes and the machine will reboot again.

That's it. Now you can select Ubuntu at the boot screen and start using it.

You can always refer to the [Installation Instructions here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer which I'm sure will work. However I wanted to install ubuntu as a native os next to windows and not to run within windows where there are performance and other issues. However I will give it a try.